# Is there an easier way to join two values in a tuple instead of concatenating them in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, refactoring

I created a program to generate sentences based on trigrams. A head of the sentence should contain the first two words separated by space and a tail should contain the last word.

I get the words in such format:
('my', 'failure', 'to')
And want to return them in a format:
('my failure', 'to')

I am not sure if creating a list and concatenating the words is an optimized idea so wanted to ask if you can see another solution to this.

Here is the code where I create the list of trigrams:

```
def create_trigrams(f):
    tokenizer = WhitespaceTokenizer()
    file_text = f.read()
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(file_text)
    trigrams_tuple = ngrams(tokens, 3)
    trigrams_list = []
    for x in trigrams_tuple:
        print(x)
        string_pair = (x[0] + " " + x[1], x[2])
        trigrams_list.append(string_pair)

    return trigrams_list
```

Comment: That's pretty much as simple and straight forward as it gets. You can do it in a few other ways like `(' '.join(x[:-1]), x[-1])` or whatever, but whether that's any better is debatable at best.

Comment: I'd rather unpack the triples `for x, y, z in trigrams_tuple:` and then do `string_pair = (f"{x} {y}", z)`. (But that's just a question of style - it doesn't really change anything.)